# Axios request to gitlab pipeline API

Tags: curl, gitlab, axios

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html

In the documentation above you can find this snippet of code (`curl request`) :

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/1/pipelines"
```

which I try to reproduce in `axios` request, but when I send a request by `curl` - it works correctly, when I send a request by using `axios`, it returns me `401 error` ( not authorized). What have I done wrong in my Axios request?

```
export const getPipelines = () => {
  return () => {
    return axios
      .get(
        `${URL}/api/v4/projects/${PROJECT_ID_VALUE}/pipelines?PRIVATE-TOKEN=${PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN_VALUE}`
      )
      .then(data => data)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are sending the token as GET parameter, you should send it in the header. 
Try this:

```
  axios.get(
    url,
    {headers: {
        "PRIVATE-TOKEN" : "token"
      }
    }
  )
  .then((response) => {
      //do something
    }
  );
```